# JavaScript password and username verification

Tags: javascript, passwords, verification

I have tried to do it but nothing seems to happen when I click the 'Submit button' this way.

```js
var pw = document.getElementById("userid");

fonk() {

  if (pw.length < 5 || > 12) {
    alert("userid must be 5-12 characters long.");

  }
}
```

```html
<fieldset style="width:20%;">
  <legend>JavaScript</legend>
  <form id="form">
    <table align="center" style="margin-top: -100px">

      <tr>
        <td><label> user id</label></td>
        <td><input type="label" name="userid"></td>
      </tr>
      <br>
      <tr>
        <td><label>Password</label></td>
        <td><input type="label" name="id"></td>
      </tr>
      <br>
      <tr>
        <td><label>Username</label></td>
        <td><input type="label" name="id"></td>
      </tr>
      <br>
      <tr>
        <td><label>Email</label></td>
        <td><input type="Email" name="id"></td>
      </tr>
      <br>
      <tr>
        <td><label>Sex</label></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="id">Male <input type="radio" name="id">Female </td>
      </tr>
      <br>
      <tr>
        <td><label>About</label></td>
        <td> <textarea> </textarea></td>
      </tr>
      <br>
      <tr>
        <td><button type="Submit" onclick="fonk()">Submit</button></td>
        <td><button type="Reset">Reset</button></td>
      </tr>

    </table>
  </form>
</fieldset>
```

user id and password should be between 7-12 characters long, and the username should only consist of characters.

Comment: You can't do a logic check like `if(pw.length < 5 || > 12)`, you need to it like `if(pw.length < 5 || pw.length > 12)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  // statement for userid check length if < 7 and > 12 alert message show 
   if(userId.value.length < 7 || userId.value.length >= 12) {
       alert('Userid should between 7 and 12 character');
    }
     // statement for password check length if < 7 and > 12 alert message show 
   if(password.value.length < 7 || password.value.length >= 12) {
       alert('password should between 7 and 12 character');
    }
   // alphabet only, for username
    let lettersRegex = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
    if(!username.value.match(lettersRegex)) {
      alert('Please input alphabet characters only');
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <fieldset style="width:20%;">
        <legend>JavaScript</legend>
      
            <table  style="margin-top: -100px">

                <tr>
                    <td><label> user id</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="userid"></td>
                </tr>
                <br>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Password</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="password"></td>
                </tr>
                <br>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Username</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="username"></td>
                </tr>
                <br>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Email</label></td>
                    <td><input type="Email" name="email"></td>
                </tr>
                <br>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Sex</label></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="radio" name="gender">Male 
                        <input type="radio" name="gender">Female 
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <br>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>About</label></td>
                    <td> <textarea> </textarea></td>
                </tr>
                <br>
                <tr>
                    <td><button  onclick="fonk()">Submit</button></td>
                    <td><button type="Reset">Reset</button></td>
                </tr>

            </table>
      
    </fieldset>
    <script>
        let username = document.getElementsByName('username')[0];
        let userId = document.getElementsByName('userid')[0];
        let password = document.getElementsByName('password')[0];
       
        function fonk() {
            if(userId.value.length < 7 || userId.value.length >= 12) {
                alert('Userid should between 7 and 12 character');
            }

            if(password.value.length < 7 || password.value.length >= 12) {
                alert('password should between 7 and 12 character');
            }
            let lettersRegex = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
            if(!username.value.match(lettersRegex)) {
              alert('Please input alphabet characters only');
            }
           
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not use and operation like this if(number1 == 1 ||  == 2) this not means number1 == 1 or 2 , you should specify variable for every operation

your if statement should be like this :

```
if(pw.length > 7 && pw.length < 12) {} //valid password
else{
    console.log("warning , invalid password");
}
```

or

```
if(!(pw.length > 7 && pw.length < 12)) //invalid password
```

Answer (score 0):

Problems in the code:

1. if (pw.length < 5 || **pw.length >** 12) {
2. var pw = document.getElementById("userid"); 
   There is no element with id "userid". change it to the correct selector.
3. var pw = document.getElementById("userid")**.value**;

btw,
Try to avoid client-side verification.
I can very easily erase the call to function or anything and evade this test.